# Computed column from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Broadcasts, Agents and Advert tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Broadcasts (
Broadcast_code INT IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
Minute_cost SMALLMONEY NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Agents (
Agent_code INT IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
Agent_percent FLOAT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Advert (
Advert_code INT IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
Agent_commission AS ((Minute_cost * Duration_in_minutes) / Agent_percent),
Broadcast_code INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Broadcasts (Broadcast_code) NOT NULL,
Agent_code INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Agents (Agent_code) NOT NULL
);
```

I want to calculate a computed column:

```
Agent_commission AS (((Minute_cost * Duration_in_minutes) / Agent_percent)
```

I tried to use VIEWS, TRIGGERS and UDF. But I can't do it.

I need the easiest way because this is a training project.
Thanks.

Comment: try view ,i think you cant use computed column from two tables, you could also UDF though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computed column cannot directly reference columns in other tables.  One option is to write a user-defined scalar function to calculate the commission.

You have two other options:

- Use a view instead of a table.
- Use a user-defined table function.

Which is best depends on how the commission will be used.  I would advise you to start with a view with the logic you want.  You may find that you want columns from several tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps 
Create table

```
CREATE TABLE Advert (
Advert_code INT IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY,
Agent_commission INT,
Broadcast_code INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Broadcasts (Broadcast_code) NOT NULL,
Agent_code INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Agents (Agent_code) NOT NULL
);
```

Select required columns

```
SELECT 
NULL AS Advert_code,
((B.Minute_cost * Duration_in_minutes) / A.Agent_percent),
B.Broadcast_code,
A.Agent_code
FROM Broadcasts B
INNER JOIN Agents A
ON (B.Broadcast_code = A.Agent_code );
```

Using the select query, you can insert into new tables

```
INSERT INTO Advert 
SELECT 
NULL AS Advert_code,
((B.Minute_cost * Duration_in_minutes) / A.Agent_percent),
B.Broadcast_code,
A.Agent_code
FROM Broadcasts B
INNER JOIN Agents A
ON (B.Broadcast_code = A.Agent_code );
```

Little clarification,
   * From where you are getting Duration_in_minutes
   * What is Advert_code, right now  am selecting null, if required you can use oracle sequence or select from another table.

You can also use same select query to create views